# Script to create URL from file ID in Google Docs

Tags: javascript, google-docs

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way using a script in a Google Doc to create a dynamic link to a Google Doc to download it as a PDF.

File links in Google Docs look like this: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILEID/edit

To download/save the file as a PDF this link is required:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE_ID/export?format=pdf

So I'm wondering if it would be possible using a script to fetch the file ID and create the PDF link above and then recall that link in the actual document (as a link or bookmark?).

In the actual document it would for example say "Download as PDF", and would have a link to the script result for https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE_ID/export?format=pdf.

I thought I'd reach out and see if someone knows if it can be done.

> NOTE: All above links point to non-existent resources and are provided for illustration only.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Its best if you make an attempt to write the necessary script and then ask for advice how to make it work correctly. Questions like "is it possible to...." invite yes or no answers that do not help you or other users.

Comment: My first thought would be to use a regular expression of some kind.